# Nifi http post -F parameter

Tags: http, http-post, apache-nifi

I am working with invokehttp module and need to make a POST request. It has three parameters: -H, -d, -F. 
-H meanings are transmitted through a couple of attributes and its meaning. 
-d - through flowfile content in a necessary view.

How do I transmit -F parameter? I want to use rest api rocket.chat on nifi.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can learn more about [ask] a question to better support the folks who can help you with your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are discussing [`curl` flags](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), not HTTP-specific request values. For the record, the `-F` flag overrides `-d` in `curl` commands.

If you are attempting `multipart/form-data` uploads, you may be interested in the work done in [NIFI-7394](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7394) to improve that handling in the `InvokeHTTP` processor.